# Label id not declared error in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple label in ASP.NET. I want to set text to it in VB.NET. The id for the label is `norecords`. The VB.NET code is like this: `lblnorecords.Text = "No Record found"`.

However, it gives me error saying: `name norecord is not declared`.

Comment: Can you plz post your HTML? Where label exist in HTML?

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblnorecords" runat="server" style="left: 25px; position: absolute; top: 50px"></asp:Label>

Comment: my label name is correct, neither i am using repeater control. but i get this error while building the project.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the name has not been registered to the .aspx.designer.vb file, which causes the problem because codebehind gets the naming info from that file. You can easily see that by using intellisense in the codebehind, and see if the variable name exists.
If it did not register it's a VS bug .

Click back and forth in .aspx a few times from source to design, and see if the name was now correctly registered in the .aspx.designer.vb file. If not, change manually.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that's your label's variable name is norecoreds, just click on the on label and see properties of the label, especially name

Answer (score 1):

If you label is inside some sort of template, its not available directly in the page scope.  Here's a rough example of how you might access it:

MyPage.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repGeneric" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepGenericItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="lblnorecords" runat="server" CssClass="separateYourCss" />

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

MyPage.aspx.cs

```
...
protected void RepGenericItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
        || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

        var myLabel = e.Item.FindControl("lblnorecords");

        myLabel.Text = "No Records Found";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

A radio button list, doesnt work well. and show that "name norecord is not declared".

Probably you have two aspx with the same name or similare name, and the lengauge doesn't kwon what page is the owner of this control.

By example y had two page with similar name page.aspx and page1.aspx and both of them were incluide in teh proyect, I exclude one of the project and all work well.

Check that.

Answer (score 1):

if you get error same this 
is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Change The Control Property : **GenerateMember = True**

Only change the property

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. After closing and re-opening Visual Studio the variable was recognized, so try restarting your design environment.